# Update a specific property from an object Array

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the array object currently am working on an angular project

```
{
    "DATA": [
        {
            "CUSTOM1": [
                {
                    "value": "Item1",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item2",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item2",
                    "isSelected": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item3",
                    "isSelected": false
                }
         
            ],
         CUSTOM2": [
                {
                    "value": "Item11",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item12",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item13",
                    "isSelected": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item14",
                    "isSelected": false
                }
         
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i wanted to update **isSelected** as **false** from **CUSTOM1**

How to do that in typescrpit

Expected a better solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not get it. You posted an input object. Please show us how you want the result object to look like after the ```i wanted to update isSelected as false from CUSTOM1``` manipulation

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Does `x.DATA.forEach(d => d.CUSTOM1.forEach(v => v.isSelected = false));` meet your needs?  What output are you looking for?  When you say "expected a better solution", what do you mean by "better" there? Better than what?  Question mark??

Answer (score 0):

run the following code:

```
let data = {
    "DATA": [
        {
            "CUSTOM1": [
                {
                    "value": "Item1",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item2",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item2",
                    "isSelected": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item3",
                    "isSelected": false
                }
         
            ],
         "CUSTOM2": [
                {
                    "value": "Item11",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item12",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item13",
                    "isSelected": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "Item14",
                    "isSelected": false
                }
         
            ]
        }
    ]
};
data.DATA[0].CUSTOM1.forEach((val) => val.isSelected = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided *looks* like a JSON string. You will first need to convert it to an JavaScript object.

Then you can loop the `DATA` array to get to each `CUSTOM1`. Then update `isSelected` property to `false`.

```js
// I shortened your example down for simplicity.
const jsonString = `{"DATA": [{ "CUSTOM1": [{ "value": "Item1", "isSelected": true}]}]}`

const parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);

const data = parsedJson.DATA;

data.forEach(d => 
  d.CUSTOM1.forEach(c1 => c1.isSelected = false)
);
```

---

Most of the time, these strings are returned from back-end APIs. We already know the shape of the returned object. It's best to create a `type` or `interface` for it. The reason why we use `TypeScript` is that we can leverage the type system.

```js
type CUSTOM1 = {
    value: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
};

type CUSTOM2 = {
    value: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
};

type DATA = {
    custom1: CUSTOM1[];
    custom2: CUSTOM2[];
};

const data: DATA[] = [
    {
        custom1: [
            { value: 'item1', isSelected: true }
        ],
        custom2: [
            { value: 'item11', isSelected: false }
        ]
    }
];
```